# How does Entity Framework support db ignorance?

Tags: entity-framework

The title really asks the question.

I am curious to know HOW Entity Framework supports database provider ignorance and what objects it creates as a result of the bulding of the query to send to the database?  I thought of DbProviderFactory first since using just the connection string and invariant name is enough to build the required objects to interact with the datasource.

All supporting resources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you read this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb738561.aspx

Comment: @EkoostikMartin Nope, didn't see it when I was searching.  Move to anwser and I will accept, unless better comes along :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework builds on the ADO.Net data provider model.

Here is some information which goes into some of those details - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb738561.aspx